# Spritekit: Dragging a SKCameraNode()

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, drag

I am rather new to Swift and SpriteKit. I made a plane move around on a big background. What I am trying to do now is DRAG the "camera" so i can see the plane when its outside my view.

I made a SKCameraNode()
I can change its position without problem. And then I tried this for drag:

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        camera?.position = CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y)
    }
}
```

The camera moves when i drag, but super fast and far far far away... 
Some ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What is receiving the user interaction, i.e., where do you have the touchesMoved?

Comment: You need to convert touch to scene coordinates